# How to add a list property to an entity using gcloud Java client?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-java

I can set a property to a new entity:

```
Entity.Builder builder = Entity.builder(actKey);
builder.set("name", someName);
```

I can see a method to add a list as a property:

```
List<Value<String>> aliases = new ArrayList<>();
builder.set("aliases", aliases);
```

I cannot find, however, how to create this `Value<String>`. There is a `DatastoreHelper.makeValue()` method in DatastoreV1, but it creates a different `Value` object.

Comment: @Entity worked for me on the CustomClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for gcloud, the answer is this:

```
Builder aliases = ListValue.builder();
while (someIterator.hasNext()) {
    aliases.addValue(StringValue.builder("some string").build());
}
builder.set("aliases", aliases.build());
```

Comment: Correct. other options are: Using ListValue.of(....), and using the various EntityBulder.set method that accept list.